# Get value from BoundField in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview, boundfield

I have two `BoundField`s one of them is pure text and the other is a numeric value.

Here's a sample of one of them:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="detailsview2" runat="server" 
                 Height="40px" Width="342px" AutoGenerateRows="false" 
                 DataSourceID="sqldatasource1" 
                 BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <CommandRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None" CssClass="tdInexistente" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nome_produto" SortExpression="nome_produto" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <InsertRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <PagerStyle BorderStyle="None" />
    <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I need to put the `BoundField`s values inside some `Session`s so I can use them on another page.

Comment: Check http://codeverge.com/asp.net.state-management/placing-boundfield-datafield-as-sess/312908

Comment: I don't think that is going to work, since i'm using DetailsView instead of a GridView

Comment: @Dusavini - On what event you are looking to fetch the value? I mean any button click or something?

Comment: @Dusavini Take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227560.aspx) especially the `EmployeeDetailsView_ItemUpdated` event handler. I think that should help you?

Comment: @Rahul Singh I was thinking that on `on page load`